# fetch data from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON code that send a form to on PHP file and I want to use data in PHP
the code is:

```
// add button .click
$('a.add').click(function(){ 
    $('#loader').show();
    var url = "/yadavari/test.php?";
    var json_text = JSON.stringify($("form[name='add']").serialize(), null, 2);
    var datas = JSON.parse(json_text);  
    ajx = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: datas,  
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(r) {

                $('#loader').hide();
                if(r.r != 0){
                    alert("ok");
                    jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'success',r.m);
                    apendtable(r.r);
                    $("tr").removeClass("odd");
                    $("tr.viewrow:odd").addClass("odd");
                    $("tr.editrow:odd").addClass("odd");
                    $('td[colspan="7"]').remove();
                }
                else{
                    jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'error',r.m,0);                        
                }
            },
    error: function(request, status, err) {
        $('#loader').hide();
            jsmsalert($('#alert_add'),'error','error msg'); 
            alert( "ERROR:  " + err + "  -  "  );

    }
```

Now I want to fetch data from this JSON code in my PHP page.
I searched but every body just said that `$string='{"name":"John Adams"}';` and so.
But I dont know that how can I have this `$string` in my PHP.

Comment: its not so clear, what is the issue?

Comment: You're not sending JSON to PHP, since you've parsed it before sending it in the AJAX call.

Comment: i added complete code

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["INPUTNAME"];
?>
```

Care about this, it suffers from security injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the php [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function on the returned string. This will convert it into an associative array:

$json2array = json_decode($json_text);
echo $json2array['name']; // "John Adams"

Comment: what i replace from my code to $json_text in your code?

Comment: OK, as mentioned you will need to change the ajax call so that it sends the json string. Change your javascript to:

data: json_text,

on the php side:

 $json_text = $_POST['add'];